# close Universe in MDAnalysis module

Tags: python, module, mdanalysis

Is it possible to close or unload a Universe in MDAnalysis module?
I didn't find any such function on MDAnalysis pages
I want to modify the trajectory with another module and then load it again in MDAnalysis, but I get a following:

```
File "/home/eh22/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lsdmap/util/metric.py", line 231, in get_distance_matrix
    for ts in u.trajectory:
File "/home/eh22/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MDAnalysis-0.8.1-py2.7-linux-ppc64.egg/MDAnalysis/coordinates/xdrfile/core.py", line 602, in __iter__
    ts = self._read_next_timestep()
File "/home/eh22/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MDAnalysis-0.8.1-py2.7-linux-ppc64.egg/MDAnalysis/coordinates/xdrfile/core.py", line 651, in _read_next_timestep
    (self.format, statno.errorcode[ts.status]), self.filename)
IOError: [Errno 14] Problem with XTC file, status exdrMAGIC: 'traj1.xtc'
```

Comment: Hi, can you please post the commands that you executed? (P.S.: We haven't been patrolling S/O for MDAnalysis questions but you can typically get a very quick answer through Google Group http://users.mdanalysis.org or by filing an issue in the GitHub issue tracker http://issues.mdanalysis.org )

Comment: I reinstalled the module and then it worked. Thanks. Next time I will go to the Google Group.